# How to deploy my APL to cloud such as heroku?

Tags: mongodb, express, heroku, react-native, cloud

I have a mobile APL using React Native(iOS and Android), MongoDB, node express, this APL come from F8app open sourced by Facebook.

I want to deploy my APL to cloud such as Heroku, cloud foundry, mLab, Firebase, AWS cloud.

How to debug it and how to deploy it?

If someone already deploys this kind APL to cloud environment, please let me know?

It would be appreciated if you could answer this question.

Thanks
Shoji Itagaki

Answer (score 0):

For heroku, create file in the project root named Procfile and inside put

```
web: COMMAND_TO_RUN_APL
```

then

```
git init 
git add -Av .
git commit -m "initial heroku push"
```

Create app APPNAME in heroku ui

```
  heroku git:add --app APPNAME 
  git push heroku master
```